# How to use Java's getCpuLoad() method?

Tags: java, cpu-usage

I tried to get current CPU load:

```java
while (true) {
     OperatingSystemMXBean os = (OperatingSystemMXBean) ManagementFactory.getOperatingSystemMXBean();
     System.out.println("CPU Load: " + os.getCpuLoad() * 100 + "%");
}
```

To my surprise, it is always 0! Note that in the mean time, I am running `stress --cpu 4`, and therefore the actual CPU load is around 20%. I checked out the JDK doc:

> Returns the "recent cpu usage" for the operating environment.

However, if I add `Thread.sleep(1000)` inside the `while` loop, then the result is expected. It seems that **some time gaps are required between calling `getCpuLoad()`** because it needs to collect some system statics in that interval.

---

I also tried to print the CPU load after the sleeping (without any loop, only twice of printing):

```java
Thread.sleep(1000);
OperatingSystemMXBean os = (OperatingSystemMXBean) ManagementFactory.getOperatingSystemMXBean();
Thread.sleep(1000);
System.out.println(os.getCpuLoad() * 100 + "%"); // still always 0%
Thread.sleep(1000);
System.out.println(os.getCpuLoad() * 100 + "%"); // about 20%
```

The result shows that the first calling of `getCpuLoad()` will always return 0. I think it is really confusing.

Is it a pitfall of JDK's implementation? Why does not JDK doc add warnings about its usage?

---

My settings:

- OS: 5.15.91-1-MANJARO
- JDK: openjdk 17.0.6 2023-01-17 LTS

Answer (score 1):

Good one.

On my machine (macos 13.2) jdk 17.06 demonstrates the same behaviour.
It does seem to be an implementation detail .

please see the code by the link below:
https://github.com/openjdk/jdk/blob/master/src/jdk.management/macosx/native/libmanagement_ext/UnixOperatingSystem.c

```
    if (last_used == 0 || last_total == 0) {
        // First call, just set the last values
        last_used  = used;
        last_total = total;
        // return 0 since we have no data, not -1 which indicates error
        return 0;
    }
```

it's a bummer though, that they didn't specify this in the docs.